# Json deserialization fails

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have following json string which I receive from API call :

```
"\"{\\r\\n  \\\"Table\\\": [\\r\\n    {\\r\\n      \\\"MaxDate\\\": \\\"2019-06-09T00:00:00\\\",\\r\\n      \\\"MinDate\\\": \\\"2019-01-26T00:00:00\\\"\\r\\n    }\\r\\n  ]\\r\\n}\""
```

I want to deserialize this string to following class structure

```
    public class Dates
    {
        public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime MinDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class TableResult
    {
        public List<Dates> Table { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to deserialize this json string to above class using Newtonsoft's Jsonconvert,

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableResult>(result);
```

it throws exception

```
Error converting value "{
  "Table": [
{
  "MaxDate": "2019-06-09T00:00:00",
  "MinDate": "2019-01-26T00:00:00"
}
 ]}" to type 'API_Test.Program+TableResult'. Path '', line 1, position 144.
```

I tried removing the spaces and \r\n from the string but still it throws exception and fails to deserialize.

Can anyone help to figure out what is wrong I'm doing?

Edit 1 :

String which I get from the API is shown in image below :
[image]

Edit 2 :
I have updated the original json string

Comment: Did you try to mark the them with attribute JsonProperty? As well you do not have to remove the slashes and etc. if you debbug and look at the string and look at it as json you will see they are not there, it is just how string represents it, As Json it will be represented normally.

Comment: I copy pasted that exact string and class definitions and it deserialized without any issue.

Comment: @JohanP can you share your code? Thanks.

Comment: `var json =
                "{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"MaxDate\": \"2019-06-09T00:00:00\",\r\n      \"MinDate\": \"2019-01-26T00:00:00\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";

            var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableResult>(json);`

Comment: I agree with @JohanP, your code works well - https://dotnetfiddle.net/zpl4Rg

Comment: @JohanP Yes. String I pasted in my original question works. I have edited my question with image. I get the string from api which is shown in image and that string is failing to parse/deserialize. Any help?

Comment: @dbc I copied the string then it is not exactly reflecting the problem. Hence I pasted the image.

Comment: View that JSON in the JSON visualizer (clicking the magnifying glass) and copy that.

Comment: I have updated the original json string.  @JohanP

Comment: @dbc I pasted the string which I get from the API response. How I convert such string with additional escaping to normal string and further deserialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API is returning a `string` that represents `json` as a string. So you first need to deserialize to `string` and then deserialize that to your `TableResult`

```
var json = "\"{\\r\\n  \\\"Table\\\": [\\r\\n    {\\r\\n      \\\"MaxDate\\\": \\\"2019-06-09T00:00:00\\\",\\r\\n      \\\"MinDate\\\": \\\"2019-01-26T00:00:00\\\"\\r\\n    }\\r\\n  ]\\r\\n}\"";

var str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableResult>(str);
```

Comment: thanks @johanp. It worked for me. Accepted this as your answer.